# Вопрос начинающего питониста

Tags: python

Прошу ответить серьезно и не смеяться над возможно глупым вопросом.
Начал изучать python и решил все изучать потихоньку, столкнулся с функциями и решил просто из головы за 2 минуты написать код. Написал сначала такое:

```
def register():
    while True:
        reg = input('Хотите зарегестрироваться? ')
        if reg == 'yes':
            nick = input('Введите свой никнейм:' )
            password = input('Введите пароль:' )
            password2 = input('Подтвердите пароль:' )
            email = input('Введите email:' )
            age = input('Введите дату рождения (DD.MM.YYYY):' )
            if password == password2:
                print(nick + ' Спасибо за регестрацию на ваш email ' + email + ' выслано сообщение с кодом')
            else:
                print('Пароли не совпадают!')
        else:
            print('Пока!')


def kod_regi():
    key = 123
    return key
```

Дальше решил их в одной функции задействовать вот так:

```
def main():
    while True:
        kod = kod_regi()
        register()
        kodik = input('Введите код из сообщения: ')
        if kodik == kod:
            print('Вы успешно подтвердили аккаунт!')
        else:
            print('Неправильный код!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

А вопрос такой, как сделать так, чтобы когда в функции `def register()` происходит условие else в `main()` не переходило к `kodik = input('Введите код из сообщения: ')`, а если выполняется все нормально он принимал `key` из `def kod_regi()` как правильный или неправильный и выводил на печать все нормально. Буду благодарен за помощь и объяснении в дальнейшем понимании мною этого. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Возвращайте из функции какое-нибудь значение (например, True — всё нормально, False — нифига не нормально) и в main() проверяйте, что именно функция возвращает

Comment: буду благодарен если хотя бы примерно покажите на примере простого кода

Comment: как сделать проверку в main()?
 Если сделаю вот так
`def kod_regi():
    key = 123
    remember_key = True
    return key, remember_key

def main():
        kod = kod_regi()
        register()
        while True:
            kodik = input('Введите код из сообщения: ')
            if kodik == kod:
                print('Вы успешно подтвердили аккаунт!')
                break
            else:
                print('Неправильный код!')`
remember_key как True, но как проверку сделать в main()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- По-поводу `while True:` циклов. Их надо использовать к месту и из них надо выходить командой `break`.

  Цикл в `register` может относиться только к попыткам ввода пароля и подтверждения пароля - мучаем клиента, пока не введет одинаковые слова.

  Цикл в `main` отнесем к попыткам ввода правильного кода, но только если клиент подтвердил желание регистрироваться, и код был отправлен. Желательно, конечно, иметь счетчик попыток, чтобы цикл не был бесконечным, если, например, код не был получен или клиент раздумал регистрироваться
- Если мы выходим из функции или прерываем цикл по оператору `if`, нет смысла рисовать к нему `else`.
- Обратите внимание на обработку условия в функциях `register` и `main`.

  В первом случае мы сначала отрабатываем ответ нет, который после единственной команды `print` идёт к выходу из функции. Этим мы делаем код более наглядным и уменьшаем отступ оставшейся части функции

  Во втором случае я не стал так делать. В итоге код под `if register():` получился на ступеньку вправо. В реальном коде наличие многих таких ступенек может говорить о неоптимальной отработке условий...
- команда `input` возвращает строку. Поэтому и сравнивать надо со строкой. Поэтому `key = '123'`

---

Получился вот такой код:

```
def register():
    reg = input('Хотите зарегистрироваться? ')
    if not reg == 'yes':
        print('Пока!')
        return False

    nick = input('Введите свой никнейм:' )

    while True:
        password = input('Введите пароль:' )
        password2 = input('Подтвердите пароль:' )
        if password == password2:
            break
        print('Пароли не совпадают!')

    email = input('Введите email:' )
    age = input('Введите дату рождения (DD.MM.YYYY):' )
    print(nick + ', спасибо за регистрацию, на ваш email ' + email + ' выслано сообщение с кодом')
    return True


def kod_regi():
    key = '123'
    return key

def main():
    if register():
        kod = kod_regi()
        while True:
            kodik = input('Введите код из сообщения: ')
            if kodik == kod:
                print('Вы успешно подтвердили аккаунт!')
                break

            print('Неправильный код!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, в начале изучения поможет разобраться очень сильно, объяснение хорошее и понял про true и false тоже. Но даже с этим кодом все равно вводя '123' в  `kodik = input('Введите код из сообщения: ')` он пишет неправильный код, не пойму как сделать так, чтобы он принимал. Где-то похоже ошибка или с передачей key в функции или еще что-то не пойму этого

Comment: @JDie Ах это, добавил в ответ...

Comment: Все разобрался, спасибо за ответ, я сначала код написал почти как ваш, только там были false не знал что можно без них, в итоге поменял на код что в впоросе, а ошибка моя ооочень глупая и невнимательность моя была, не принимал код, т.к вместо key = '123' у меня было key = 123 это просто ударить себя по лбу ладошкой, очень невнимательно повел себя, вам огромное спасибо за ответ и объяснение